# Healing an Eidolon

Tags: pathfinder-1e

This is my first time playing a Summoner in Pathfinder, and I have a question regarding the Eidolon: Will a normal Cure spell work on it? The reason I ask, there is a specific spell to cure the Eidolon, Rejuvenate Eidolon. This made me think regular cure spells do not work on the Eidolon. Then I saw the Undead Appearance evolution. It states, when applied to the Eidolon, negative energy heals the Eidolon, and positive energy harms it. This suggested to me that normal Cure spells from a cleric should be able to heal it. Please assist!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Cure Spells Work**

> A summoner begins play with the ability to summon to his side a powerful **outsider** called an eidolon. The eidolon forms a link with the summoner, who, forever after, summons an aspect of the same creature. An eidolon has the same alignment as the summoner that calls it and can speak all of his languages. Eidolons are treated as summoned creatures, except that they are not sent back to their home plane until reduced to a number of negative hit points equal to or greater than their Constitution score. In addition, due to its tie to its summoner, an eidolon can touch and attack creatures warded by protection from evil and similar effects that prevent contact with summoned creatures.

Outsider is a creature type indicating a living being not native to the Prime Material Plane. Unless specifically specified otherwise, all living beings are healed by applications of positive energy such as *Cure Light Wounds*.

The Rejuvenate Eidolon line of spells are a method for the Summoner to natively heal and support their own Eidolon.

Comment: They are also there because that spell line is the only way for the Synthesist build to heal their fused Eidolon. http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateMagic/spellcastingClassOptions/summoner.html#synthesist-%28archetype%29