# Summoner rejuvenate eidolon with words of power

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoner, eidolon

I want to play a Summoner who uses words of power. However I cannot seem to combine any words that will rejuvenate my eidolon.  I don't feel that he should have to rely on the healers to repair damage to his own creation and the key part of his class.
Am I missing a combination, or did the game designers overlook this?  I am having a hard time finding the answer to this.

If it's not in the game, anyone have a homebrew fix?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. Thank you for participating and have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A typical [wordcaster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/words-of-power) [summoner](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/words-of-power/words-by-class/summoner-word-list) can't heal his [eidolon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner#TOC-Eidolon)

A wordcaster summoner gets no healing words (*Ultimate Magic* 179-80). Adding a healing word to the summoner's word list isn't even possible using the feat [Extra Word](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/words-of-power) (*Ultimate Magic* 166), that feat only adding to the caster's list of words known from its extant list. It appears the designers *either* did, in fact, overlook this aspect of the wordcaster summoner *or* made a deliberate choice to not give the summoner any healing words as a stealth nerf.

However, I'd argue a homebrew fix unnecessary as the skill [Use Magic Device](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/use-magic-device) is a class skill for both the typical and [unchained summoner](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/summoner-unchained). It shouldn't be that big of a deal to spend a few turns after combat or upon summoning the eidolon for the summoner to make a few Use Magic Device skill checks [to heal an injured eidolon using a *wand of cure light wounds*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/31629/8610) or by using similar magic items.

Comment: Thanks for working on this. At least now I know I wasn't just missing the right combination of Words.         I personally think this must of been over looked in the final edit.  Requiring a wand and Use Magic Device to accomplish something core to the class seems a poor fit and more of a patch.  Since All current types of magic are built off these Words. (As stated in the description of WoP).    I think I'll either add a "Eidolon" Word or a "Rejuvenate" Word.  Perhaps a "Repair" word that could also work on constructs.   But no "Healing" words I do understand that would unbalance the game

Comment: You're welcome. I, too, suspect, like you said, given the brevity and limited nature of the wordcaster system, that the designers were simply reluctant to give the summoner a healing word that would heal *anything* when the usual base class was only able to heal the eidolon. Unless it's the end of the adventuring day, I've never seen a summoner, essentially, *waste* his spells per day healing his eidolon when a *wand of cure light wounds* was available, be it *via* the summoner and the skill Use Magic Device or the party cleric, bard, inquisitor, oracle, or whoever.